# Crop raster files with Polygon and writing the output with the same filename

Tags: polygon, crop, raster, geotiff

i have a lot of rasterfiles (satellite images, all available in geotiff .tif extension). Some files are splitted into all bands as single files, some files have multiple bands. As this uses a lot of space on my harddrive, i want to crop every file with the area of my interest, which i have as a shapefile polygon.

I am close to my own solution and get the cropped images as new .tif files with the following code:

```
library(raster)
rasterfiles = list.files(path=getwd(), pattern = "*.TIF", full.names=TRUE)
s = stack(rasterfiles)
shp = readOGR("Area.shp")
rasterfiles_crop = crop(s, extent(shp))

output = writeRaster(rc, 'out.tif', format="GTiff", overwrite=TRUE, bylayer = TRUE)
```

With this code I receive the filenames out_1.tif, out_2.tif etc...

Unfortunately the resulting files have only 1 band, so R recognizes the 1st band, only, when it comes to a multi-band TIF image.

I want to keep all bands and the original filename and just add "_crop" at the end of the new one. May someone can help me here how i have to change the code?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write them in a loop

```
library(raster)
library(rgdal)

shp <- readOGR("Area.shp")     

infiles <- list.files(path=getwd(), 
                      pattern="*.TIF", 
                      full.names=TRUE)

outfiles <- file.path(YourOutputPath, 
                      paste0(basename(tools::file_path_sans_ext(infiles)),
                      "_crop.tif")
                      )

for (i in seq_along(infiles)) {
  r <- crop(raster(infiles[i]), shp)
  writeRaster(r, filename=outfiles[i])
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this code works perfectly! readOGR is a function inside the rgdal package which has to be loaded, too.

Comment: I realised, that this method only works, when the original file has 1 band inside the TIFF images. Or in other words: The otherbadns are not in the resulting files. i can't use something like stack(list.files(path.....)

Any hints how to keep all bands?

Comment: Oh, you are right! But with stack instead of raster it should work. Do you get an error if you use stack in the loop?

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution now, the following code lists all TIF files in a folder and a multi-band tif keeps its bands after the crop process:

```
library(raster)
library(rgdal)

setwd("input-folder")

 ## polygon with crop-extend ##
shp <- readOGR("area.shp")

 ## load tif files ##
infiles = list.files(path=getwd(),
                     pattern="*.tif$|*.TIF$")

 ## Filenames with desired suffix and output place ##
outfiles = file.path("D:/Downloads/BDA/Output",
                     paste0(basename(tools::file_path_sans_ext(infiles)),
                     ".tif"))

 ## crop and output settings (compression and datatype)
 for (i in seq_along(infiles)) {
      r = crop(stack(infiles[i]), shp)
      writeRaster(r, filename=outfiles[i],
                  bylayer=FALSE,
                  format="GTiff",
                  datatype="INT1U",
                  options="COMPRESS=ZIP",
                  overwrite=TRUE)
 }
```

Thank you Richard for the nice loop code!

Concerning the datatype: It would be nice, if R can check which datatype the inputfiles have and choose the same one automatically for the cropped output. Right now i have to specify the datatype manually. Otherwise the output files will be as float32 (FLT4S) even if the input files just have 8bit unsigned (INT1U) or 16bit signed (INT2S).

```
 datatype= same.as.input.file
```